# Load data in template page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am creating a website in which I need to sell products. I am stuck at the product page of the website.

The big e-commerce website like amazon.com must have a template of the product page and they dynamically load all the data including image of product, price, reviews from the database. I also want to create a similar product page where on clicking a link of product, it automatically loads all the images, price and info stored in the database and show it.

If another product is clicked, everything loads on that very same `html/php` template page and I don't have to make different page for different products. How can I do that?

I have been searching for a solution to this for many days, but I don't know what exactly to search for to get the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a php page, say, `load_products.php` and pass get parameters like `load_products.php?product_id=1`. 
Change the id (as per the database setup) and get the corresponding product details from database.

---

### Edit : Detailed Answer

**Database**

Table: `table_products`

```
+--------------------------+---
| id |   name   | details  | ...
+--------------------------+---
| 1  | Product1 | Details1 | ...
| 2  | Product2 | Details2 | ...
            ...
+--------------------------+---
```

I shall show you how it is done with MySQL database.

**PHP Code**
`load_products.php`

```
// Establish connection to database
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('products_database_name');

// Display All the Products
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products");
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $id=$row["id"];
    $name=$row["name"];
    echo "<a href='load_products?id=$id'>$name</a>";
}

// Display the details of a particular product based on the input click from user
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE id=$id");
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $details=$row["details"];
        $name=$row["name"];
        echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$details</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

A really bare bones implementation, yet fully working and you can see the output on your localhost in 15 minutes. You can build on top of this.

You can search for : Loading images from database, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) to enhance the website interface, using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) on top of this and so on..

Comment: @Ayush is this what you are looking for ? If so, I can expand the answer after sometime !!

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I would appreciate if you expand the same..

Answer (score 0):

Please find the Improved version

products.php page

```
 // Establish connection to database
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('products_database_name');

// Display All the Products
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products");
$productsPerRow = 4; 
$columnWidth = (int)(100 / $productsPerRow);
$count = 0; //count product displayed

echo "<table>
        <tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $count++;
    $id    = $row["id"];
    $name  = $row["name"];
    $image = $row["image"]; //image name with extension, upload it in the images folder
    echo "<td width='" . $columnWidth ."' >
            <img src='images/" . $image ."' border='0'/><br />
            <a href='load_product.php?id=$id'>$name</a>
         </td>";
    if($count%$productsPerRow==0)
        echo"</tr><tr>";

}

//close empty cells
if ($count % $productsPerRow > 0) {
    echo "<td colspan='" . ($productsPerRow - ($count % $productsPerRow)) .
    "'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
}

//close table
echo "</table>";
```

load_product.php page

```
// Establish connection to database
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('products_database_name');

// Display the details of a particular product based on the input click from user
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE id=$id");
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $details=$row["details"];
        $name=$row["name"];
        echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$details</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```